# Why does sys.stdin.close() work differently in IDLE vs script

Tags: python, sys

```
try:
    sys.stdin.close()
except:
    pass
raise SystemExit(None)
```

The above seems to be the code for exit/quit function of site package.
While researching about it I realized sys.stdin.close() seems to be invoking the below window in IDLE

[image]

But when running scripts from other places like cmd, sys.stdin.close() is seemingly doing nothing and the program is closed by raise SystemExit(None)

Why is this the case??

I tried to find the reason behind this in code but could not find any

Searched in all places I could think of but no answer

Answer (score 1):

IDLE is catching your SystemExit and creates a pop up to give you to opportunity to have the executing script stop while IDLE continues to run.  If you hit escape or click the Cancel button, your script's execution will end and IDLE will continue.  If you click OK your script will exit and IDLE will also exit.